# How to export a multi-layer ggplot to googleVis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-visualization, rcharts, plotly

I created a plot with `ggplot` with 4 different layers.

The bulk of the data is in blue dots, while the datapoints that meet `condition A` are surrounded by a green halo.

Likewise, the datapoints that meet `condition B` are surrounded by a red halo.

In addition, datapoints that meet `condition C` are surrounded by a larger yellow halo.

I want all of these 4 colors to be possible in a point, so I don't want to use `color=factor(condition)` or something like that.

The thing is I want to make this plot interactive so that people can hover over the points, and most importantly, see the `row.names` of a given point.
How can I give googleVis a layered ggplot?

I would like to use googleVis because I think this is the only tool that would let me display the name of the data point in the bubble, but I am open to trying plotly or Rcharts as well if this is possible.

[image: This is what the plot looks like:]

ggplot code:

```
genePlot <- ggplot() + 
list(geom_point(data=correlSelect[c("GENE_A", "GENE_2", "GENE_3", "GENE_4", "GENE_5", "GENE_6", "GENE_7", "GENE_8", "GENE_9", "GENE_10"),] , aes(condition1, condition2), colour="yellow", alpha=1, size=5) 
+ geom_point(data=correlSelect[row.names(resSignif1),] , aes(condition1, condition2), colour="red2", alpha=.5, size=3) 
+ geom_point(data=correlSelect[row.names(resSignif2),] , aes(condition1, condition2), colour="seagreen3", alpha=.5, size=3) 
+ geom_point(data=correlSelect, aes(condition1, condition2), colour="steelblue", alpha=.3))
```

And my data frame looks like this:

```
       cond1  cond2  score
GENE_A  .5     .2     -10
GENE_B  .3     .8     -3
GENE_C  .4     .1     -5
GENE_D  .8     .8      6
GENE_E  .7     .4      8
GENE_F  .1     .6      2
.
.
.
GENE_Z  .9     .3      5
```

I am only plotting the values in `cond1` and `cond2`, but I would like people to be able to hover over the points and see the `row.name (GENE_X)` and the value in the `'score'` column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try and convert your `ggplot` plot to a `plotly` one (via `ggplotly()`, see https://plot.ly/ggplot2/). Let me know if some layers are not supported or the conversion is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks, mkcor. I tried ggplotly( ) but the size of the second, third and fourth layers is not respected. They are plotted as small points within the blue points, instead of as halos.

Comment: I also have not been able to figure out if Plotly can display the names of the observations in the hover bubbles. For now I have only been able to display the values that are being plotted with Plotly.

Comment: Yep, Plotly lets you customize the hover data. Here is [an example bubble chart](https://plot.ly/~jackp/1835). Here's [a question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152856/customise-the-infowindow-tooltip-in-r-plotly) about custom hover with R. Can you post a reproducible example so we can check out your code?

Comment: @MateoSanchez, that is awesome and just what I mean! I will update my question to include my ggplot code and a snippet of my data frame in R. Thanks!

Comment: I have just updated my question to better reflect what I am trying to do.