# ggplotly - R, labeling trace names

Tags: r, plotly

I'm new to plotly and not able to find the relevant documentation on how to name the traces so a meaningful label appears in plot rendered by `ggplotly`.  Here is the [ggplotly site](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/facet/) that shows a number of examples.  What is needed to show a meaningful label on hover instead of the value followed by trace0, trace1, etc.

For example, in the first plot, how can the labels appear so it shows:

Proportion: value

Total bill:  value

Ideally, I would like to do this directly in R rather than through the web interface.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also edit any of the plotly figure properties *after* the ggplot2 conversion but *before* you send it to plotly. [Here is an example](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/user-guide/#modify-ggplot2-figure) that changes the legend entry names manually. I'll repeat it here:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4), y=c(1, 5, 3, 5), group=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'))
g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=group)) + geom_point()

# an intermediate step that `ggplotly` calls
p <- plotly_build(g)

# manually change the legend entry names, which are "trace0", "trace1" in your case
p$data[[1]]$name <- 'Group A'
p$data[[2]]$name <- 'Group B'

# send this up to your plotly account
p$filename <- 'ggplot2-user-guide/custom-ggplot2'
plotly_POST(p)
```

[The extended example here](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/user-guide/#modify-ggplot2-figure) explains in more detail how and why this works.

Note that *in general* the legend item names, e.g. "trace0", are going to be the labels that you grouped by in the dataframe (as in ggplot2).

Comment: I haven't tested this example but I had to use `p$x$data[[1]]$name <- 'Group A'`. note the addition of `x`.

Answer (score 10):

Using ggplot2 and Plotly you can set the `text`. You'll want to [install Plotly and get a key](http://plot.ly/r). Here are two examples. Example one:

```
data(canada.cities, package="maps")
viz <- ggplot(canada.cities, aes(long, lat)) +
    borders(regions="canada", name="borders") +
    coord_equal() +
    geom_point(aes(text=name, size=pop), colour="red", alpha=1/2, name="cities")
    ggplotly()

ggplotly(filename="r-docs/canada-bubble")
```

This yields [this plot](https://plot.ly/~MattSundquist/19399/lat-vs-long/) with the name of Canadian cities available on the hover.

[image]

Example two:

```
install.packages("gapminder")
library(gapminder)

ggplot(gapminder, aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, color = continent, text = paste("country:", country))) +
geom_point(alpha = (1/3)) + scale_x_log10()  

ggplotly(filename="ggplot2-docs/alpha-example")
```

Which yields [this plot](https://plot.ly/~MattSundquist/19612/lifeexp-vs-gdppercap).

[image]

For more information, see our [R docs](http://plot.ly/r) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152856/customise-the-infowindow-tooltip-in-r-plotly) on how to overwrite the `hover_text` element. Plotly's native R API lets you add [more controls](https://plot.ly/r/#chart-events) to your plots. Thanks for asking Brian. We'll add a new section to our docs on this as well. Disclaimer: I work for Plotly.