# ggplotly overrides scale_fill_manual() labels argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to generate an interactive version of a plot I made using ggplot2, and would like to maintain the legend labels. The plot is a bar chart of a particular neighborhood's income distribution each year for 6 years.

My ggplot scale_fill_manual() labels argument is :

```
 scale_fill_manual(values = values,
                          labels = c("< 10,000",
                                     "10,000 to 14,999",
                                     "15,000 to 24,999",
                                     "25,000 to 34,999",
                                     "35,000 to 49,999",
                                     "50,000 to 74,999",
                                     "75,000 to 99,999",
                                     "100,000 to 149,999"))
```

when I run `p <- ggplotly(p)` my labels change to the labels that I grouped the data by in my data set, as expected. For example, checking the first 12 labels of my new plot gives:

```
    > p$Incomes[1:12]
 [1] Households..Estimate..Less.than..10.000 
 [2] Households..Estimate..Less.than..10.000 
 [3] Households..Estimate..Less.than..10.000 
 [4] Households..Estimate..Less.than..10.000 
 [5] Households..Estimate..Less.than..10.000 
 [6] Households..Estimate..Less.than..10.000 
 [7] Households..Estimate...10.000.to..14.999
 [8] Households..Estimate...10.000.to..14.999
 [9] Households..Estimate...10.000.to..14.999
[10] Households..Estimate...10.000.to..14.999
[11] Households..Estimate...10.000.to..14.999
[12] Households..Estimate...10.000.to..14.999
```

Following the example found here [ggplotly - R, labeling trace names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098836/ggplotly-r-labeling-trace-names),
I run as a test:

```
p$Incomes[[1]] <- "< 10,000"
```

with the error:

```
Warning message:
In `[[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = c(NA, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 17L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Pretty much anything I try to do to change the stored value throws me an error of some sort, whether I use `[]` or `[[]]`, `as.factor` or `as.integer` or `as.character`,  I even tried to use `<<-` (which is horrible) but still got an error.

My various efforts to fix this have been unfruitful and not particularly well planned because I am pretty much at a loss as to what the problem is. I would appreciate any method by which I can manually edit the legend. Please let me know if I need to reformat my question or provide more information.