# Tooltips in plotly+ggplot2+geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I would like to suppress the y-coordinate in the tooltip appearing on the points, just displaying the letters.

Can this be done?

```
library(plotly) #https://github.com/ropensci/plotly
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data_frame(x=0:100, y=x+rnorm(101,0,10), ttt=letters[1+runif(101,0,26)])
p <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x,y,text=ttt)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(p)
```

The solution described here [Adding custom tooltip to plotly using R and ggplot2 syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175766/adding-custom-tooltip-to-plotly-using-r-and-ggplot2-syntax)

Does not solve my problem. I would like to get rid of the value of the y-coordinate in the popup, and this is not achieved by the note mentioned.

I fact, with geom_point at the moment one gets sliding arrows along the x-axis for the x-coordiates, and the y coordinate on the popup close to the point. Perhaps it would be more consistent if the y-coordinate also would be displayed with an arrow on the y-axis and only a user defined text next to the point itself.

Can this be done?

BTW: I do have a free plotly account (since a few days), but when using the plotly packages, I do not need to sign in in RStudio. Is this standard behavior now?

Comment: Can you also add packages you're using?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik updated.

Comment: @Pascal I think it is dplyr.

Comment: **Side note**: Example not reproducible if you don't have an account I don't know where.

Comment: @Pascal Technically, one would need a [plot.ly](http://help.plot.ly/how-to-sign-up-to-plotly/) account.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  Thanks. Basically, I won't apply for an account.